# basic remote login by python

Tags: python, redirect, curl

I am new in python. I am practicing it. 
Now i am trying to login remotely into my wordpress blog by python. 
Here is the code sample :

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, re

cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
redirect_handler= urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler, urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
url = 'http://example.com/abc/wp-login.php'
data = urllib.urlencode({"log":"user","pwd":"pass","rememberme":"forever","wp-submit":"Log In","redirect_to":
"http://example.com/abc/wp-admin","testcookie":1})

req = opener.open(url, data)
get_page = req.read()
get_url  = req.geturl()
print get_page
```

But it's not login properly ( or it is not redirecting properly. ) when i check the return page . I can do it easily in php with `curl` which has a option to follow location. I think it's most probably the redirection problem. Isn't it ? So which function should use here ?

Regards

**Update**

It's working. It's need to check the redirected url. So i put this line after previous code and verify that login is successful .
`req2 = opener.open('http://symsell.com/abc/wp-admin').read()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `requests` and your code will be much simpler.

Modified quick start example from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

Of course you might also add support for cookies there, but you asked for basic authorization and that is shown.