# How to use Python to login and detect error if the combination is wrong

Tags: python, wordpress

i want to connect to my site using python script and detect when the login fails.
for example in wordpress when the login is incorrect the URL don't forward from wp-login.php to /wp-admin/ and gives you this message :

```
ERROR: The password you entered for the username admin is incorrect. Lost your password?
```

i want the method to detect this two kinds of errors :
1-URL don't change.
2-Error message.
and this is my code so far to detect error message :

```
import urllib2
import re

html_content = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/login').read()

matches = re.findall('Error', html_content);

if len(matches) == 0: 
   print 'Login Error'
else:
   print 'Login Successfull'
```

thanks for any helps guys ^_^

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code, working or otherwise, so that we can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: You need to connect your website to a database in order to check logins, first of all.

Comment: have a look at this -
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803838/basic-remote-login-by-python. You will get some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that when working with Python for web dev, it's most convenient to use an already established framework, such as Flask which uses Werkzeug (simple and efficient).

I suggest you read up on Python web development here

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

and head to http://www.codecademy.com and finish the Python course first if you are unfamiliar with how to use it.

From Python official doc:

"The Web Server Gateway Interface, or WSGI for short, is defined in PEP 333 and is currently the best way to do Python web programming. While it is great for programmers writing frameworks, a normal web developer does not need to get in direct contact with it. When choosing a framework for web development it is a good idea to choose one which supports WSGI."

I suggest Flask because it is really, really simple. But also take a look at

https://pelican.readthedocs.org/en/3.4.0/

This may not be the answer you were hoping for, but without showing us your current code, and telling us what you've tried, we cannot help any more :)

or to put it more bluntly, turn to StackOverflow only after you've invested some effort into researching in order to solve your problem, and failed after trying to implement a solution or two.